# Delete rows with less than 7 Characters

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains customer information for a business, with 12 variables and 1,246 rows.  The CustomerID column has errors in it.  Every customer ID should have 7 characters (ex., VALLE03), but some appear as “GTO1” or “003” -- the entire row where these errors appear need to be deleted.

I was thinking that if I could sort the df by the number of characters in “CustomerID” I could manually remove the rows that don’t have 7 characters.  But I’m not sure how to sort by number of characters, or if there is a better way.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your file is named data and CustomerID is a char column:

```
data = data[(which(nchar(data$CustomerID) == 7)),]
```

the *which* command filters the rows given a boolean argument.

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated!  For future reference, do you know how to sort a data frame by the number of characters in a particular column?

Comment: use `order`  in `data[order(nchar(data$CustomerID)),]`

Answer (score 0):

`nchar()` is the functions you're searching...Cus

```
   nchar('VALLE03')
```

Then subset the data.frame via `df[nchar(df$CustumerID) == 7, ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `nchar`. Suppose your data.frame is `dat` you can do:

```
dat[nchar(dat$CustomerID)==7, ]
```

The code above will select all rows that contains at leas 7 characters in `CustomerID` column.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add a solution with **dplyr** that also uses nchar:

```
    #library(dplyr)
    filtered <- dplyr::filter(df,nchar(as.character(CustomerID))==7)
```